# How to check if a property is an IList and if so assign a new empty value

Tags: c#, .net-core

I would like to do something like this in my `EntityBase` class:

```
public EntityBase()
{
    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

    foreach (var property in this.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (property is IList)
            property.SetValue(property, new IList());
    }
}
```

To ensure there are no `null` lists in any of my entites

However, this doesn't work for

1. `if (property is IList<object>)`
2. `if (property is IList<T>)`

because in case 1, the property is skipped (as it is of type e.g. `IList<Package>` and not `object`) and in case 2, I do not have access to `T` in the current context

Is something like this possible, or do I just need to manually assign to all `IList` properties in each entity's constructor?

Comment: The `GetProperties()` method is returning [PropertyInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) objects. You can check the `PropertyType` property of that object.

Comment: @Progman I am trying that, but if I check `if (property.PropertyType is IList)` it skips over `IList` properties - presumably because the REAL type is actually `IList<Package>` not just `IList`

Comment: @Bassie - more likely because `property.PropertyType` if of type `Type`...

Comment: You might want to fiddle around with [Type.IsGenericType](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.type.isgenerictype) and [Type.GenericParameterAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.type.genericparameterattributes) -- maybe the *easier* way is to change the entities: `public IList<X> XList { get; } = new List<X>();` -- added bonus: noone can set them to `null` again afterwards. -- If they are "generated" entities, simply change the template. -- `property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && (property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>))`

Comment: new IList() is invalid.

Comment: as @Kristjan Kica said, you cannot create a new instance of an interface, you would have to create a new List() and if it's generic then you'd need to find what the generic type is and then create a new instance

Answer (score 0):

So going on the fact that your aim is "To ensure there are no null lists in any of my entites"

Why would you not just instantiate the lists in the constructor of each entity that has a list. Using the foreach method in the question will be slow and is not very clean at all.

Comment: The assumption is, that there are already a lot of classes inheriting `EntityBase` containing a lot of lists. So manually changing all of them is probably deemed to be too much effort.

Comment: Then it's a trade off between effort and code maintainability vs overall system efficiency. Reflection like this is slow and ultimately it seems like you're not fixing the problem, just hacking on top of it. Also shouldn't `EntityBase` be `abstract` ??

Comment: I totally agree that it would be better for OP in the long run to fix the source and not just apply bandaid.